# How to update report connected to Power BI datasets

Tags: powerbi, dataset, report, directquery

I work with a many data tables which I am using for reports creation. Because data sources are slow and tables have huge size ( Odata ), I have to change the way how to update data.

My idea was to create one DataSet per entity ( Table ) in Power BI workspace and update it once per a day. New reports will be connected to this DataSet instead of Odata source ( So when reports will be updated, they download data from Dataset, not from Odata source which is a much slower and non effective ). Also the new reports will not download the data paralel, but from a single data source.

I created 2 DataSets from most used entities, remove non important columns and upload them to workspace. DataSets are uploaded once per day which works great.

After that, I created a new test report in Power BI, connected a DataSets as a source ( DirectQuery ) and did whole calculations in this report using DAX.

After I upload this report, I was not able to update it via workspace.

`{"error":{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error","pbi.error":{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"Premium_ASWL_Error_Details_Label","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Refresh is not supported for datasets with a calculated table or calculated column that depends on a table which references Analysis Services using DirectQuery."}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}`

Can someone help me with this ?

If I do the update via desktop, everything works great.

I Tried to update reports many times, but I am not able to find what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of DataSets I used DataFlows in workspace, which work same.

Updating Datasets is not able if you are using calculated DAX columns.

Thanks.

Comment: Correct, if you are doing the same ETL on the same tables for many datasets, dataflows are the way to go. You can create query level custom columns for more basic functions.  If you are using all tables the same way, i would still encourage loading them all the to same dataset so they can be consumed by multiple reports.